# Jest: expect or expect...not based on Boolean

Tags: jestjs

Using `test.each` in Jest, I'd like to pass in a Boolean that toggles whether I expect something or not.

This is the type of repetitive code I'm trying to avoid:

```js
if (expectFoo) {
  expect(anObject).toContainEqual(
    expect.objectContaining({
      name: "foo"
    })
  );
} else {
  expect(anObject).not.toContainEqual(
    expect.objectContaining({
      name: "foo"
    })
  );
}
```

Here is some pseudocode that illustrates my preferred (cleaner, shorter) approach:

```js
expect(anObject).yesOrNo(expectFoo).toContainEqual(
  expect.objectContaining({
    name: "foo"
  })
);
```

Is there anything like this in Jest?

Comment: This is the case for custom matcher.

Comment: OK, but I don't really want to have to rebuild OOTB Jest matchers like `.toContainEqual()`, `objectContaining()`, etc. from scratch.  I'm not really sure how to write a custom replacement for something like `not` that goes in between an `expect()` and another matcher.  Can it be done?

Comment: Didn't notice the comment. Here's an example, in case it's still relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Built-in matchers [aren't public API](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/10329) but can be imported from the same internal module that is used by Jest:

```
import matchers from 'expect/build/matchers';
```

Custom matchers can wrap and compose built-in matchers:

```
expect.extend({
  toContainFoo(received, expectFoo = true) {
    const isNot = !expectFoo ? !this.isNot : this.isNot
    this.isNot = isNot; // affects error message
    const expected = matchers.objectContaining({
      name: "foo"
    });
    const result = matchers.toContainEqual.call(this, received, expected);
    result.pass = !isNot; // affects assertion logic
    return result;
  }
})
```

Comment: This isn't precisely the kind of thing I was hoping for, since you have to implement it separately for each matcher or combination of matchers.  It would be nice to have something like a generic `not` replacement that takes a Boolean param.  But it's certainly better than having to rebuild the logic of the matchers themselves.  Thanks!